# why i cant see tracking markers in 3d viewport

Tags: tracking

I have just finished tracking and camera solving my footage. after setting up tracking scene, the markers are visible in the 3d viewport but only in the motion tracking panel.[image: 3d viewport in motion tracking panel]

but when i switch into the default panel, the markers are not there
[image: 3d viewport in default panel]
how would I make the trackers appear in the default viewport? currently I haven't enabled "link empty to track"

Answer (score 4):

On the Display Overlays drop down menu located to the left of the buttons you change Render modes(wireframe, previz and render) you'll find an option to turn on Motion Tracking overlays. Enable that and more options will be available underneath that to suit your preference.